# Failure to run .jar (uiautomator.jar) files on Mac

Tags: java, android, jar, appium, android-uiautomator

**I want to run the .jar files on Mac but they don't work.**

I call them in two ways:

1. Double clicking on the file itself, **I get the following error:**
   `Java Application launch failed. Check Console for possible error messages related to "/Users/ amir/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/android.jar”.`
2. I try to run the following command in the terminal:
   `java -jar /Users/amir/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/uiautomator.jar`

   **And then I find this error:**
   `no main manifest attribute, in /Users/amir/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/uiautomator.jar`

Here is my .zprofile file configuration for Java:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_361.jdk/Contents/Home

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/bin:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/amir/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

I have this problem for more than 1 week and I have not found any solution for it.

I am trying to run the .jar file